# Data export from BCP

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2012, bcp

Changing from SQL Server Management Studio 2008 to 2012 has resulted in my cmd code not working :

```
bcp "SELECT  [id],[AlmLog_TimeStamp],[AlmLog_ID],[AlmLog_State] 
FROM DB02REA05461.[dbo].[AlarmLog] 
ORDER BY [id]" 
queryout wtg02.txt -c -S10.51.23.51\NAID -Ucus -PsFO
```

It gives me the following error:

> SQLState = 08001, NativeError = 22
>   Error = [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]SQL Server Native Client 11.0
>   does not support connections to SQL Server 2000 or earlier versions.
>   SQLState = 08001, NativeError = 22
>   Error = [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]Client unable to establish connection

Any help on altering the code from `cmd` would be appreciated.

Comment: If you are using SQL Server 2000, which the error would suggest, it's really time to upgrade.

Comment: Please provide your SQL server version and the operating system you use and which is is running the SQL server itself.

Comment: What database engine version are you running against? (`SELECT @@VERSION`) Which **compatibility level** does your database have? (`SELECT name, compatibility_level FROM sys.databases
WHERE name = 'YourDatabaseNameHere'`). SQL Server **2012** (and its Management Studio) do no longer support SQL Server 2000 (as an engine version) or a compatibility level of `80` (which corresponds to SQL Server 2000) - time to upgrade!

Comment: It's on a Windows Server 2008R2 machine, with the server being on a "Microsoft Windows NT 6.1 (7601)".

Comment: SQL Server 8.0.760.
I see, All of you come to the same conclusion, thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command line tools provided by SSMS 2012 are not compatible with SQL Server 2000.  You will need to either upgrade your SQL Server 2000, or downgrade your SSMS back to 2008.

Answer (score 0):

I have just had this issue. As SQL server 2000 does not support bcp as an alternate solution I just exported the table to csv.